# How to figure out nginx 502 errors when logs are ok

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, php, wordpress

I'm running a blog (on Wordpress) with nginx 1.6.0 + HHVM 3.1.0 + memcache on Ubuntu 14.04. Every few hours (~12-20h), nginx throws a 502 error and my blog gets down.

I tried to figure it out, but I have no idea:

- Memory and CPU are ok (770MB free memory when blog was down)
- nginx log doesn't show something useful, just warnings (see log below)
- HHVM log doesn't show something useful, just warnings (see log below)

What else can I do?

### Logs & configs

**nginx error.log**

```
2014/06/16 04:38:10 [warn] 5460#0: duplicate extension "eot", content type: "application/vnd.ms-fontobject", previous content type: "application/octet-stream" in /etc/nginx/mime.types:83
2014/06/16 04:38:11 [warn] 5464#0: duplicate extension "eot", content type: "application/vnd.ms-fontobject", previous content type: "application/octet-stream" in /etc/nginx/mime.types:83
2014/06/16 04:39:26 [warn] 5507#0: duplicate extension "eot", content type: "application/vnd.ms-fontobject", previous content type: "application/octet-stream" in /etc/nginx/mime.types:83
2014/06/16 04:39:33 [warn] 5523#0: duplicate extension "eot", content type: "application/vnd.ms-fontobject", previous content type: "application/octet-stream" in /etc/nginx/mime.types:83
2014/06/16 04:39:34 [warn] 5527#0: duplicate extension "eot", content type: "application/vnd.ms-fontobject", previous content type: "application/octet-stream" in /etc/nginx/mime.types:83
2014/06/16 04:58:34 [warn] 961#0: duplicate extension "eot", content type: "application/vnd.ms-fontobject", previous content type: "application/octet-stream" in /etc/nginx/mime.types:83
2014/06/16 05:03:46 [warn] 951#0: duplicate extension "eot", content type: "application/vnd.ms-fontobject", previous content type: "application/octet-stream" in /etc/nginx/mime.types:83
2014/06/17 07:33:56 [warn] 961#0: duplicate extension "eot", content type: "application/vnd.ms-fontobject", previous content type: "application/octet-stream" in /etc/nginx/mime.types:83
```

**nginx.conf**

```
user www-data;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;
worker_processes auto;
worker_rlimit_nofile 65000;

events {
    worker_connections 2048;
    multi_accept on;
    use epoll;
}

http {
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;

    access_log off;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log crit;

    keepalive_timeout 20;
    client_header_timeout 20;
    client_body_timeout 20;
    reset_timedout_connection on;
    send_timeout 20;

    proxy_buffer_size   128k;
    proxy_buffers   4 256k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size   256k;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type text/html;
    charset UTF-8;

    gzip on;
    # gzip_static on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_min_length 256;
    gzip_comp_level 4;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    open_file_cache max=65000 inactive=20s;
    open_file_cache_valid 30s;
    open_file_cache_min_uses 2;
    open_file_cache_errors on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

**nginx blog config: chefgrill.conf**

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;

  server_name chefgrill.de;
  index index.php;

  if ($http_user_agent !~ FeedBurner) {
    rewrite ^/feed/ http://feeds.feedburner.com/chefgrill last;
  }

  location / {
    root  /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    root  /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    fastcgi_keep_conn on;
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
    fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;  
    fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    include fastcgi_params;
  }

}
```

**hhvm error.log**

```
\nWarning: Cannot access property on non-object in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-content/themes/bbq/archive.php on line 68
\nWarning: Cannot access property on non-object in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-content/themes/bbq/archive.php on line 68
\nWarning: Cannot access property on non-object in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-content/themes/bbq/archive.php on line 68
\nWarning: Parameter 1 to W3_Plugin_TotalCache::ob_callback() expected to be a reference, value given in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2935
\nWarning: Parameter 1 to W3_Plugin_TotalCache::ob_callback() expected to be a reference, value given in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2935
\nWarning: Cannot access property on non-object in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-content/themes/bbq/archive.php on line 68
\nWarning: Cannot access property on non-object in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-content/themes/bbq/archive.php on line 68
\nWarning: Cannot access property on non-object in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-content/themes/bbq/archive.php on line 68
\nWarning: Cannot access property on non-object in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-content/themes/bbq/archive.php on line 68
\nWarning: Cannot access property on non-object in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-content/themes/bbq/archive.php on line 68
\nWarning: Parameter 1 to W3_Plugin_TotalCache::ob_callback() expected to be a reference, value given in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2935
\nWarning: Cannot access property on non-object in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-content/themes/bbq/archive.php on line 68
\nWarning: Cannot access property on non-object in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-content/themes/bbq/archive.php on line 68
\nWarning: Cannot access property on non-object in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-content/themes/bbq/archive.php on line 68
\nWarning: Cannot access property on non-object in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-content/themes/bbq/archive.php on line 68
\nWarning: Cannot access property on non-object in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-content/themes/bbq/archive.php on line 68
\nWarning: Cannot access property on non-object in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-content/themes/bbq/archive.php on line 68
\nWarning: Cannot access property on non-object in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-content/themes/bbq/archive.php on line 68
\nWarning: Cannot access property on non-object in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-content/themes/bbq/archive.php on line 68
\nWarning: Cannot access property on non-object in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-content/themes/bbq/archive.php on line 68
\nWarning: Cannot access property on non-object in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-content/themes/bbq/archive.php on line 68
\nWarning: Parameter 1 to W3_Plugin_TotalCache::ob_callback() expected to be a reference, value given in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2935
\nWarning: Parameter 1 to W3_Plugin_TotalCache::ob_callback() expected to be a reference, value given in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2935
\nWarning: Parameter 1 to W3_Plugin_TotalCache::ob_callback() expected to be a reference, value given in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2935
\nWarning: Parameter 1 to W3_Plugin_TotalCache::ob_callback() expected to be a reference, value given in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2935
\nWarning: Parameter 1 to W3_Plugin_TotalCache::ob_callback() expected to be a reference, value given in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2935
\nWarning: Parameter 1 to W3_Plugin_TotalCache::ob_callback() expected to be a reference, value given in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2935
\nWarning: Parameter 1 to W3_Plugin_TotalCache::ob_callback() expected to be a reference, value given in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2935
\nWarning: Parameter 1 to W3_Plugin_TotalCache::ob_callback() expected to be a reference, value given in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2935
\nWarning: Cannot access property on non-object in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-content/themes/bbq/archive.php on line 68
\nWarning: Cannot access property on non-object in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-content/themes/bbq/archive.php on line 68
\nWarning: Cannot access property on non-object in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-content/themes/bbq/archive.php on line 68
\nWarning: Cannot access property on non-object in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-content/themes/bbq/archive.php on line 68
\nWarning: Cannot access property on non-object in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-content/themes/bbq/archive.php on line 68
\nWarning: Cannot access property on non-object in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-content/themes/bbq/archive.php on line 68
\nWarning: Cannot access property on non-object in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-content/themes/bbq/archive.php on line 68
\nWarning: Cannot access property on non-object in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-content/themes/bbq/archive.php on line 68
\nWarning: Cannot access property on non-object in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-content/themes/bbq/archive.php on line 68
\nWarning: Cannot access property on non-object in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-content/themes/bbq/archive.php on line 68
\nWarning: Parameter 1 to W3_Plugin_TotalCache::ob_callback() expected to be a reference, value given in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2935
\nWarning: Parameter 1 to W3_Plugin_TotalCache::ob_callback() expected to be a reference, value given in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2935
\nWarning: Parameter 1 to W3_Plugin_TotalCache::ob_callback() expected to be a reference, value given in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2935
\nWarning: Parameter 1 to W3_Plugin_TotalCache::ob_callback() expected to be a reference, value given in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2935
\nWarning: Parameter 1 to W3_Plugin_TotalCache::ob_callback() expected to be a reference, value given in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2935
\nWarning: Parameter 1 to W3_Plugin_TotalCache::ob_callback() expected to be a reference, value given in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2935
\nWarning: Parameter 1 to W3_Plugin_TotalCache::ob_callback() expected to be a reference, value given in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2935
\nWarning: Parameter 1 to W3_Plugin_TotalCache::ob_callback() expected to be a reference, value given in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2935
\nWarning: Parameter 1 to W3_Plugin_TotalCache::ob_callback() expected to be a reference, value given in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2935
\nWarning: Parameter 1 to W3_Plugin_TotalCache::ob_callback() expected to be a reference, value given in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2935
\nWarning: Parameter 1 to W3_Plugin_TotalCache::ob_callback() expected to be a reference, value given in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2935
\nWarning: Parameter 1 to W3_Plugin_TotalCache::ob_callback() expected to be a reference, value given in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2935
\nWarning: Cannot access property on non-object in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-content/themes/bbq/archive.php on line 68
\nWarning: Cannot access property on non-object in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-content/themes/bbq/archive.php on line 68
\nWarning: Cannot access property on non-object in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-content/themes/bbq/archive.php on line 68
\nWarning: Cannot access property on non-object in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-content/themes/bbq/archive.php on line 68
\nWarning: Cannot access property on non-object in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-content/themes/bbq/archive.php on line 68
\nWarning: Cannot access property on non-object in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-content/themes/bbq/archive.php on line 68
\nWarning: Cannot access property on non-object in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-content/themes/bbq/archive.php on line 68
\nWarning: Cannot access property on non-object in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-content/themes/bbq/archive.php on line 68
\nWarning: Cannot access property on non-object in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-content/themes/bbq/archive.php on line 68
\nWarning: Cannot access property on non-object in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-content/themes/bbq/archive.php on line 68
\nWarning: Parameter 1 to W3_Plugin_TotalCache::ob_callback() expected to be a reference, value given in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2935
\nWarning: Parameter 1 to W3_Plugin_TotalCache::ob_callback() expected to be a reference, value given in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2935
\nWarning: Parameter 1 to W3_Plugin_TotalCache::ob_callback() expected to be a reference, value given in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2935
\nWarning: Cannot access property on non-object in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-content/themes/bbq/archive.php on line 68
\nWarning: Cannot access property on non-object in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-content/themes/bbq/archive.php on line 68
\nWarning: Cannot access property on non-object in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-content/themes/bbq/archive.php on line 68
\nWarning: Cannot access property on non-object in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-content/themes/bbq/archive.php on line 68
\nWarning: Cannot access property on non-object in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-content/themes/bbq/archive.php on line 68
\nWarning: Cannot access property on non-object in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-content/themes/bbq/archive.php on line 68
\nWarning: Cannot access property on non-object in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-content/themes/bbq/archive.php on line 68
\nWarning: Cannot access property on non-object in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-content/themes/bbq/archive.php on line 68
\nWarning: Cannot access property on non-object in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-content/themes/bbq/archive.php on line 68
\nWarning: Cannot access property on non-object in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-content/themes/bbq/archive.php on line 68
\nWarning: Parameter 1 to W3_Plugin_TotalCache::ob_callback() expected to be a reference, value given in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2935
\nWarning: Parameter 1 to W3_Plugin_TotalCache::ob_callback() expected to be a reference, value given in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2935
\nWarning: Parameter 1 to W3_Plugin_TotalCache::ob_callback() expected to be a reference, value given in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2935
\nWarning: Parameter 1 to W3_Plugin_TotalCache::ob_callback() expected to be a reference, value given in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2935
\nWarning: Parameter 1 to W3_Plugin_TotalCache::ob_callback() expected to be a reference, value given in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2935
\nWarning: Parameter 1 to W3_Plugin_TotalCache::ob_callback() expected to be a reference, value given in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2935
\nWarning: Parameter 1 to W3_Plugin_TotalCache::ob_callback() expected to be a reference, value given in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2935
\nWarning: Parameter 1 to W3_Plugin_TotalCache::ob_callback() expected to be a reference, value given in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2935
\nWarning: Parameter 1 to W3_Plugin_TotalCache::ob_callback() expected to be a reference, value given in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2935
\nWarning: Parameter 1 to W3_Plugin_TotalCache::ob_callback() expected to be a reference, value given in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2935
\nWarning: Parameter 1 to W3_Plugin_TotalCache::ob_callback() expected to be a reference, value given in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2935
\nWarning: Parameter 1 to W3_Plugin_TotalCache::ob_callback() expected to be a reference, value given in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2935
\nWarning: Parameter 1 to W3_Plugin_TotalCache::ob_callback() expected to be a reference, value given in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2935
\nWarning: Parameter 1 to W3_Plugin_TotalCache::ob_callback() expected to be a reference, value given in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2935
\nWarning: Parameter 1 to W3_Plugin_TotalCache::ob_callback() expected to be a reference, value given in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2935
\nWarning: Parameter 1 to W3_Plugin_TotalCache::ob_callback() expected to be a reference, value given in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2935
\nWarning: Parameter 1 to W3_Plugin_TotalCache::ob_callback() expected to be a reference, value given in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2935
\nWarning: Parameter 1 to W3_Plugin_TotalCache::ob_callback() expected to be a reference, value given in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2935
\nWarning: Parameter 1 to W3_Plugin_TotalCache::ob_callback() expected to be a reference, value given in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2935
\nWarning: Parameter 1 to W3_Plugin_TotalCache::ob_callback() expected to be a reference, value given in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2935
\nWarning: Parameter 1 to W3_Plugin_TotalCache::ob_callback() expected to be a reference, value given in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2935
\nWarning: Parameter 1 to W3_Plugin_TotalCache::ob_callback() expected to be a reference, value given in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2935
\nWarning: Parameter 1 to W3_Plugin_TotalCache::ob_callback() expected to be a reference, value given in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2935
\nWarning: Parameter 1 to W3_Plugin_TotalCache::ob_callback() expected to be a reference, value given in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2935
\nWarning: Parameter 1 to W3_Plugin_TotalCache::ob_callback() expected to be a reference, value given in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2935
\nWarning: Parameter 1 to W3_Plugin_TotalCache::ob_callback() expected to be a reference, value given in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2935
\nWarning: Parameter 1 to W3_Plugin_TotalCache::ob_callback() expected to be a reference, value given in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2935
\nWarning: Parameter 1 to W3_Plugin_TotalCache::ob_callback() expected to be a reference, value given in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2935
\nWarning: Parameter 1 to W3_Plugin_TotalCache::ob_callback() expected to be a reference, value given in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2935
\nWarning: Parameter 1 to W3_Plugin_TotalCache::ob_callback() expected to be a reference, value given in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2935
\nWarning: Parameter 1 to W3_Plugin_TotalCache::ob_callback() expected to be a reference, value given in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2935
\nWarning: Parameter 1 to W3_Plugin_TotalCache::ob_callback() expected to be a reference, value given in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2935
\nWarning: Parameter 1 to W3_Plugin_TotalCache::ob_callback() expected to be a reference, value given in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2935
\nWarning: Parameter 1 to W3_Plugin_TotalCache::ob_callback() expected to be a reference, value given in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2935
\nWarning: Parameter 1 to W3_Plugin_TotalCache::ob_callback() expected to be a reference, value given in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2935
\nWarning: Parameter 1 to W3_Plugin_TotalCache::ob_callback() expected to be a reference, value given in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2935
\nWarning: Parameter 1 to W3_Plugin_TotalCache::ob_callback() expected to be a reference, value given in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2935
\nWarning: Parameter 1 to W3_Plugin_TotalCache::ob_callback() expected to be a reference, value given in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2935
\nWarning: Parameter 1 to W3_Plugin_TotalCache::ob_callback() expected to be a reference, value given in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2935
\nWarning: Parameter 1 to W3_Plugin_TotalCache::ob_callback() expected to be a reference, value given in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2935
\nWarning: Parameter 1 to W3_Plugin_TotalCache::ob_callback() expected to be a reference, value given in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2935
\nWarning: Cannot access property on non-object in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-content/themes/bbq/archive.php on line 68
\nWarning: Cannot access property on non-object in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-content/themes/bbq/archive.php on line 68
\nWarning: Cannot access property on non-object in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-content/themes/bbq/archive.php on line 68
\nWarning: Cannot access property on non-object in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-content/themes/bbq/archive.php on line 68
\nWarning: Cannot access property on non-object in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-content/themes/bbq/archive.php on line 68
\nWarning: Cannot access property on non-object in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-content/themes/bbq/archive.php on line 68
\nWarning: Cannot access property on non-object in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-content/themes/bbq/archive.php on line 68
\nWarning: Parameter 1 to W3_Plugin_TotalCache::ob_callback() expected to be a reference, value given in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2935
\nWarning: Parameter 1 to W3_Plugin_TotalCache::ob_callback() expected to be a reference, value given in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2935
\nWarning: Parameter 1 to W3_Plugin_TotalCache::ob_callback() expected to be a reference, value given in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2935
\nWarning: Parameter 1 to W3_Plugin_TotalCache::ob_callback() expected to be a reference, value given in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2935
\nWarning: Parameter 1 to W3_Plugin_TotalCache::ob_callback() expected to be a reference, value given in /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2935
```

Comment: Have you looked up what a 502 error is and considered how it may be generated in your environment ?

Comment: Yes, and I can't imagine, why a 502 error occurs, especially after hours of running

Comment: nginx is just a proxy, look into why your PHP code is failing. I think there is a problem with Wordpress caching plugin.

Comment: Also are you running this under hhvm-fscgi?

Comment: nginx typically throws 502's when the backend is down, so you should make sure HHVM is running. Also, have a look at the syslogs - maybe the memory was free, because the OOM killed (HHVM) processes?!

Comment: @MKzero You're right: The HHVM process is killed. There are 2 strange HHVM error.log entries: `Core dumped: Aborted` and `data error`. I'll have a look at this